# Office Web Applications Hardware Requirements

Tags: raid, sharepoint-2010

I am looking at deploying Sharepoint with Office Web Applications and trying to get the approvals for the necessary hardware.  Looking at the requirements from Microsoft (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431682.aspx) they seem a little much.  A beefy web server and a beefy application server for 10 concurrent users?

Anyway, my question is regarding the disk requirement.  The Microsoft says the following.

- 3 x 146 GB, 15 K SAS (3 RAID 1 disks) Disk 1: Operating system Disk 2: Swap and BLOB cache Disk 3: Logs and temp directory)

I am either reading this wrong or I am having a very large brain fart.  Are they saying they want 3x RAID 1 arrays (thus needing 6x 146GB drives), or 3x 146 drives in a single RAID 1 array with separate partitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it's not just you.  Trying to slog through that bucket of fail they call minimum requirements leaves you feeling queasy.

Frankly, I have no idea what they're trying to say.  If you go [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=fd1eac86-ad47-4865-9378-80040d08ac55&displaylang=en) and download the OfficeWebAppsCapacityPlanningDoc.docx you'll see where they cut that snippet from.  Unfortunately the context doesn't really help either.

I believe that those recommendations are for the web front end, in which case based on what those drives are going to be doing, I would do 3 separate RAID 1 arrays (6 disks).

You can look [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc298801.aspx) for more reading on how to configure the SQL backends.